# RSpec - stubbing an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I've added the following method into the middle of a project:

```
def finishes_after_venue_shuts?
  return unless venue && finish
  day = regular_day ? regular_day : start.strftime('%a').downcase
  finish > venue.openingtimes.where(default_day: day).pluck(:finish)[0]
end
```

This has caused 1000+ tests to fail within the project. They're failing with the following error code:

```
ArgumentError:
  comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with nil failed
```

I've tried to stub out the method as follows but am apparently doing something wrong:

```
before do
  allow(Event.any_instance).to receive(:finishes_after_venue_shuts?).and_return(false)
end
```

What is the correct syntax for stubbing out the method and simply returning false rather than performing the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close :)

```
allow_any_instance_of(Event)
  .to receive(:finishes_after_venue_shuts?)
  .and_return(false)
```

But using `allow_any_instance_of` is considered a bad practice, so more appropriate would be using a double:

```
let(:event) { instance_double(Event, finishes_after_venue_shuts?: false) }

allow(Event).to receive(:new).and_return(event)
```

Comment: Works perfectly - many thanks Andrey will accept the answer shortly.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko what about if finishes_after_venue_shuts? would be an class method??

Comment: @TWONEKSONE `allow(Event)..to receive(:finishes_after_venue_shuts?).and_return(false)`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I am getting `Event` does not implement `#finishes_after_venue_shuts?` error. I think it's because my method is class method `self.finishes_after_venue_shuts?`. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: yes, you're doing something wrong. You have class instance method, whereas you're stubbing instance method, which does not exist and, logically, it is throwing an error. Decide, what you want to stub (class instance method `Event.finishes_after_venue_shuts` or an instance method `Event#finishes_after_venue_shuts`) and stub it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
Event.any_instance.stub(:finishes_after_venue_shuts).and_return(false)
```